# Перехват сетевых данных

Tags: windows, драйвер, windows-7, сеть, ассемблер

Подскажите решение для перехвата траффика под windows 7. Перехват через RAW Sockets не работает. Pcap использовать не хочу. Хочется способ не требующий установки.

Заинтересовался драйверами. Мне начал нравиться http://reqrypt.org/windivert.html , но он внезапно не имеет цифровой подписи и просто так не ставится, а подписанного варианта я не нашел. Их BarbaTunnel ставится без подписанных драйверов, с чего я просто фигею. Тут вопрос, кто знает, где получить сертификат для подписывания драйверов? И есть ли в этом смысл? Я так понял это стоит порядка 100$ в год.

Есть ли еще хорошие драйверы, от которых лишь требуется перехватывать все пакеты идущие через сетевой интерфейс?

А может проще не заниматься этой ерундой и заглянуть в недра системы? Какие функции достаточно перехватить, чтобы получать весь траффик в программе? Меня интересует это дело для firefox, точнее для flash приложения.

Comment: Ставим [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), в настройках прокси указываем localhost:8888 и смотрим весь трафик.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, у меня есть sock прокси, через которое все это гонялось. Хочется чего-то более совершенного, без перенастройки браузера.

Comment: wireshark.org (стоит упоминания, хотя для вашей задачи это оверкилл)

Answer (score 1):

Proxyfier или socksescort, добавляешь туда свой прокси, через который гонял траф, браузер настраивать не придется, программы перехватят трафик и направят его через твой сокс, я второй пользуюсь, она удобнее.